# Create a .dll from a Silverlight Web Application

Tags: silverlight, web-applications, dll, on-screen-keyboard

I programmed a Virtual Keyboard (On Screen Keyboard) as a Silverlight Web Application, now I want to use this Keyboard in an other Silverlight Application (call the Keyboard when clicking a Textbox). I thought I could create a .dll and use this in my other Application.

So is it possible to create a .dll File from a Silverlight Web Application?

Thank you for reading,

Knut Hansen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to convert it into a Silverlight Class Library. There are some things to look out for, but it isn't too hard.

It is one of the options when you create a new project in Visual Studio.

See Microsoft's documentation for more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838164(v=vs.95).aspx#silverlight_class_library_project

Comment: Thank you very much Chris for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

also you can think of a web service, in this way your application can be used by anyone else, of course you can specify users of your app. I think web services are more recent and using them is more future-oriented, give it a go!

Comment: Hi Ali, thanks for your reply! Thats a very good idea I didnt think about that! Thank you very much!